# XML Schema with complext type containing <xs:all> and <xs:any>?

Tags: xsd, sequence, indicator, complextype

I want to define a complex type that contains elements that may or may not exist, and also allows for additional undefined elements so I've got something like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="MyType">
 <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="A" type="xs:float" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
  <xs:element name="B" type="xs:float" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
  <xs:element name="C" type="xs:float" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
  <xs:any minOccurs="0" processContents="skip"/>
 </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I don't want to force the order using `<xs:sequence>` so I want to change the `<xs:sequence>` to `<xs:all>` but then `<xs:any>` isn't allowed. Is there some way to accomplish this?

Comment: I didn't mark the code in my description so it wasn't visible. I know about <all> already, but I want to use <all> and <any>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validating XML with XSDs ... but still allow extensibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347822/validating-xml-with-xsds-but-still-allow-extensibility)

Answer (score 0):

To allow any order, use this:

```
<xs:complexType name="MyType"> 
 <xs:all minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"> 
  <xs:element name="A" type="xs:float" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
  <xs:element name="B" type="xs:float" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
  <xs:element name="C" type="xs:float" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
 </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

But then, you can't have an `<any>` inside an `<all>`.
Nor can you have them both inside one type, either directly or as an extension.