# <xs:any> inside an <xs:all> XSD 1.0 workarounds?

Tags: java, maven, xsd, jaxb, xsd-1.0

In my Java (Maven) project I'm using [JAXB 2.2.11](https://jaxb.java.net/) to rebuild instances of a class from an XML payload received by our servers. I have an `.xsd` schema defining the class, which works great in conjunction with JAXB to rebuild an instance of the type I want. The issue I'm having is that those payloads can (without any notice or warning) have extra elements which I don't really care about.

One of the places where those extra elements can appear is within an `xs:all` tag. I do like having the functionality of said [`xs:all`](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_all.asp) tag:

> The all element specifies that the child elements can appear in any
>   order and that each child element can occur zero or one time.

However, I don't want to get a parsing error while processing an XML payload that contains extra attributes. An `xs:any` tag inside the `xs:all` would work great, but it's not permitted in XSD 1.0 (according to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_sequence.asp) and this other [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3367162/289011)) and apparently, JAXB doesn't support XSD 1.1. Also, the way `JAXB` treats the `any` or the `anyAttribute` is very interesting, because it puts all the unknown nodes into a map, so I can log it saying *"Hey! We are receiving an attribute that we don't really care about as of now, but maybe you'll find it somehow useful in the future?"*

I've read about [Xsom](https://xsom.java.net/), that supports XSD 1.1, but apparently, it doesn't return an *instance* of the class you want, but more generic set of hash-maps and lists, therefore losing my type checking, which is something I don't want to.

So... Is there any way of *pretending* to have an `xs:any` within an `xs:all`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct.  XSD 1.0 does not allow `xsd:any` within `xsd:all`; XSD 1.1 does.

### Workarounds for XSD 1.0 not allowing `xsd:any` in `xsd:all`

1. Confine `xsd:any` to a fixed wrapper element such as `expansion` with `xsd:all`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <xsd:element name="root">
       <xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:all>
           <xsd:element name="a"/>
           <xsd:element name="b"/>
           <xsd:element name="expansion">
             <xsd:complexType>
               <xsd:sequence>
                 <xsd:any maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
               </xsd:sequence>
             </xsd:complexType>
           </xsd:element>
         </xsd:all>
       </xsd:complexType>
     </xsd:element>
   </xsd:schema>
   ```
2. Abandon the unordered allowance of `xsd:all` and let the `xsd:any` elements follow in sequence:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <xsd:element name="root">
       <xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:sequence>
           <xsd:element name="a"/>
           <xsd:element name="b"/>
           <xsd:any maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         </xsd:sequence>
       </xsd:complexType>
     </xsd:element>
   </xsd:schema>
   ```