# Is it possible to define an XSD that doesn't care about additional elements?

Tags: xsd, xml-serialization, c#-4.0

I have an XSD that defines and element which has been decrecated for some time, I now wish to remove this element and remove it from the class definition (I'm using the .net XmlSerializer with an XmlReaderSettings set to fire validation events).

I'd like some of our clients who can't / won't remove the deprecated element from their xml to still be able to use my service, but I don't want to retain the additional Properties in my code or the xsd file (that way new client won't get the property and call me asking what it means)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to use [xs:any](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/schema_complex_any.asp). I'll recommend you to look at [Creating Extensible Content Models](http://www.xfront.com/ExtensibleContentModels.html.) which describes another very interesting ways. It is the bast place which I know about the subject.

Another [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347822/validating-xml-with-xsds-but-still-allow-extensibility/) could give also interesting information about this subject.